# SECharts - various charts and interesting findings on all SE sites (as of August 2012)

Tags: app

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]

### About

SECharts - StackExchange charts application is a static web application where you can browse some data regarding all 37 SE sites. I have created SECharts to learn Hadoop and Apache Pig on the Amazon EMR and while looking for some data to work with I found SE Data Dump. I have used the latest data dump available (August 2012) and processed that. Once I got the results I wanted to present them nicely and that's how the SECharts were born.

#### License

It's free, it doesn't contain any ads or anything like it and so far is just a pet project

#### Download

You can see the app working at: [SECharts](http://stackexchagecharts.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com)
If you want to, you can download the individual files, there is no zip prepared. All are hosted on Amazon S3 as a static website.

#### Platform

Tested on Mac OS with Chrome, Firefox and Safari

### Contact

More information about this app and how I build it is available at my blog:
[www.sofwarepassion.com](http://www.softwarepassion.com/big-data-analysis-with-hadoop-pig-and-stack-exchange-data-dump/)

### Code

I have created the script for analysing the SE Data using Apache Pig and then run it on Amazon EMR. For the presentation layer I created a Java Velocity template for a single SE page and then a simple java program that would fetch the results, parse the template and generate 37 pages for all the data I had. The index page I did by hand.

Any questions, suggestions, opinions etc can be posted on my blog at: [www.softwarepassion.com](http://www.softwarepassion.com/big-data-analysis-with-hadoop-pig-and-stack-exchange-data-dump/)